# JPA Union on two @OneToMany Collections on the parent object

Tags: hibernate, jpa

- Account has many Payments (paymentType, date)
- Account has many Letters  (letterType, date)
- You have 10,000 accounts, each having at least 5 payments and letters.

What's the query to return all Accounts whose paymentType = 'check' and lettertype = 'mail'?

The other way to think of is to do two queries on Payment and Letter and add them but due to the nature of an api I'm using (SpringBatch), I'm only exposed to a 'Query' in AbstractJpaQueryProvider so I'd rather have an Account collection to be returned than an Object which I then have to cast to properties in each of the services that uses this interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to filter parent records based on some criteria applied to their child records, it might be better to use an "exists" expression, like

```
select a from Account
where exists(select p from Payment where p.account = a and p.paymentType='check') 
 and exists(select l from Letters l where l.account = a and l.letterType='mail')
```

This will avoid the Cartesian join problem introduced by multiple @OneToMany join navigations in a single query.

See also: 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E16764_01/apirefs.1111/e13046/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_exists

Answer (score 1):

```
select a from Account a join a.payments p join a.letters l where p.paymentType='check' and l.letterType='mail'
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out I'd actually need a "UNION" of Payments and Letters, and hence query needs to run on the the collection object level. What would be the equivalent of the above?